# Is there a way to exit only the php file being included?

Tags: php

So, I have a sidebar.php that is included in the `index.php`. Under a certain condition, I want `sidebar.php` to stop running, so I thought of putting `exit` in `sidebar.php`, but that actually exits all the code beneath it meaning everything beneath `include('sidebar.php');` in `index.php` all the code would be skipped as well. Is there a way to have `exit` only skip the code in the `sidebar.php`?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Just use `return;`

Do also be aware that it is possible to actually return something to a calling script in this way.

if your parent script has `$somevar = include("myscript.php");` and then in myscript.php you do say... `return true;` you will get that value in `$somevar`

Answer (score 18):

Yes, you just use `return;`. Your sidebar.php file might look something like this:

```
<?php

if($certain_condition) {
    return;
} else {
    // Do your stuff here
}

?>
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a really old question, but I've recently taken over the code base of another developer who used exit religiously, meaning that the parent file that included various files had to be designed in such a way that the include of the module files were done at the end so it didn't cut off the page. I wrote a small PHP script to replace all occurrences of "exit;" with "return;".

```
if($handle = opendir("path/to/directory/of/files")) {
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if("." === $file) continue;
        if(".." === $file) continue;

        $pageContents = file_get_contents($file);
        $pageContents = str_replace("exit;", "return;", $pageContents);
        file_put_contents($file, $pageContents);

        echo $file . " updated<br />";

    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone.